# How can I increase the padding around nodes in a fitted box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, fit

I have code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm, minimum size=.9cm}, % Adder
}

\newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
    node at (1,-3) [sum] (C) {\large$C$}
    node [sum, right of=C] (theta) {\large$\theta$}
    ;
    \draw[->](C) -- node {} (theta);

    \node[draw,fit=(C) (theta)] {$N_d$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My main question is how to increase the padding of the box around the nodes C and theta. As a bonus, I'd like to move the label $N_d$ to the bottom right of the box.

Comment: You can add  `xshift=2cm`, for example, to move the node over.

Comment: Can I move the label with `xshift`?

Comment: I thought of using larger invisible nodes at the same positions as the visible ones, but I'm not sure how to do that..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `inner sep` key for the surrounding node is probably what you're after. To move the label, the easiest is to make a new node, placed relative to the surrounding node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm, minimum size=.9cm}, % Adder
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\node at (1,-3) [sum] (C) {\large$C$};
\node [sum, right of=C] (theta) {\large$\theta$};

\draw[->](C) -- node {} (theta);

\node[inner sep=10pt,draw,fit=(C) (theta)] (box) {};
\node[above left] at (box.south east) {$N_d$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```